# Routing using OpenLayers and pgrouting

Tags: openlayers-2, pgrouting

I would like to do a **Dijkstra** routing using pgrouting and OpenLayers. I have the downloaded osm data. I am following the workshop given in this [link](http://www.pgrouting.org/docs/ol-workshop/index.html). But since I am very new to this I found it difficult to understand [this](http://www.pgrouting.org/docs/ol-workshop/ch01.html) page.

Can anyone explain this page to me?

Comment: Sorry, but the link to Chapter 01 you posted has nothing to do with OpenLayers. And you better give more details about what you don't understand. Otherwise it's difficult to help you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use GeoExt if want to try it another way. Look at the official workshop as it's more up-to-date: http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/geoext_client.html