# How to create shortest route and multiple routes service using openlayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, postgis, web-mapping, geoext

I created a digital database of many important features and locations of my city. and I want to create a web application in which shortest distance between two locations can be calculated and displayed. Is it possible with openlayers as client scripting. My shapefiles are in postgis.

What I am expecting is :

- The database contains all roads, point features etc.
- When the user types a location, the required location name can be listed out from the database and then user can similarly select another location
- Then my technique is to find the nearest road points for the two locations (may be using buffer method) and then
- finding the shortest and possible routes between the two road points along the road vector features.

  But I don't know how to write the code and algorithms.

Comment: Please check http://workshop.pgrouting.org/ or ftp://ftp.remotesensing.org/pgrouting/foss4g2009/docs/workshop_manual.pdf for examples

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  When answering it is always best to include more than just a URL or only URLs because they can sometimes disappear.  If possible, can you expand your Answer with a paragraph or two about what will be found at those URLs that directly answers the Question, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's possible using PostGIS with pgRouting and OpenLayers. You'll find an extensive tutorial here: http://pgrouting.org/docs/ol-workshop/index.html

In a similar question ([routing using openlayers and pgrouting](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26996/routing-using-openlayers-and-pgrouting)) the following GeoExt for pgRouting tutorial is recommended: http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/geoext_client.html

You'll want to look into auto-complete scripts to support users when typing location names.

Finding nearest points on line has been discussed multiple times, e.g. [Nearest neighbor between point layer and line layer?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/396/nearest-neighbor-between-a-point-layer-and-a-line-layer)

You'll have to learn to write code ... or hire someone.

Comment: thanks and i extended my question..please tell me if i can do that all using pgrouting

Comment: http://www.kneipenculture.de/ol_osm_routing.zip this link is given in pgrouting http://pgrouting.org/docs/ol-workshop/index.html and is not working